# Feeding my friend's animal on Shabbas

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, animals

If my friend has a pet such as a dog or cat, can I feed it on Shabbas? Do we say it's prohibited because I am not responsible to feed it (Shulchan Aruch) or do we say since my friend has to feed him I can also?

Comment: Do you mean while your friend is there (e.g. you feed the dog some treats while you're visiting), or while your friend is away and he's asked you to care for the animal in his absence?

Answer (score 9):

The Biur Halacha on [Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 324](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1588):11 sv "ויוני ביתות" writes that since the animal belongs to a Jew, and the animal does not eat from *hefker*, and the owner is allowed to feed the animal, another person can also feed the animal.

> ויוני בייתות - שמגדלות אותן בבית וכ"ז מיירי כשהם שלו כן מוכח מא"ר
>   ולענ"ד אין זה ברור דכיון שהם של ישראל ואינם אוכלין מהפקר כי היכי דמותר
>   לבעליהן להכין להם מזונות ה"נ מותר לאדם אחר:‏